# FEM-ception: Using output of NDSolve FEM as input in another FEM problem

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, regions, mesh, finite-element-method

After having solved a Stokes flow problem in Mathematica on a subdomain `RegionCapillary`, I would like to solve an advection-diffusion problem on a larger domain `RegionShell` which contains the previous domain. This means taking the `InterpolatingFunction` returned by `NDSolve FEM` for the Stokes problem and setting it to zero everywhere on `RegionShell`, so that the Stokes velocity field can be used in the advection term of the transport problem on `RegionShell`. The solution, produced by Comsol, shows concentration boundary layers:

[image]

The left picture shows a solution of the velocity field $\boldsymbol{u}$ of the Stokes problem $\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{u}=0, \nabla p=\mu\nabla^{2}\boldsymbol{u}$ solved on the domain `RegionCapillary`. The right pictures shows a solution of concentration field $c$ from the advection-diffusion problem $Pe\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla c=\nabla^{2}c$ solved on `RegionShell`. Let's see if I can retrieve the Comsol solution in Mathematica.

```
   RegionCapillary = 
      RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0.1}, {0.9, 0.2}], 
         Rectangle[{0, 0.8}, {0.9, 0.9}], 
         Rectangle[{0.8, 0.2}, {0.9, 0.9}] ];
RegionShell = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];

<< NDSolve`FEM`
StokesOp := {
   -Inactive[Laplacian][ u[x, y], {x, y}] + D[ p[x, y], x], 
   -Inactive[Laplacian][ v[x, y], {x, y}] + D[ p[x, y], y],
   (* incompressibility div u = 0 *)
   Div[{u[x, y], v[x, y]}, {x, y}]
   } ;

bcs := {
         DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 10^3, x == 0 && y > 0.5],
         DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y < 0.5],
         DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, True]
         };

Clear[xVel, yVel, pressure];
AbsoluteTiming[{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
         NDSolveValue[{StokesOp == {0, 0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v, 
     p}, {x, y} \[Element] RegionCapillary,

    Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
                  "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-4}}
            ]];

DensityPlot[Sqrt[
        xVel[x, y]^2 + yVel[x, y]^2], {x, y} \[Element] 
   RegionCapillary, 
      PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "velocity magnitude", 
      PlotPoints -> 30] // Quiet
```

This code produces the expected Stokes flow solution:

[image]

Here is my attempt to tackle the reaction-diffusion problem:

```
   Pe = 10^2;
advectionOp := 
 If[{x, y} \[Element] RegionCapillary, 
   Pe {xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][c[x, y], {x, y}], 0] - 
  Inactive[Laplacian][c[x, y], {x, y}]

bcs := {DirichletCondition[c[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && 0.8 < y < 0.9], 
   DirichletCondition[c[x, y] == 1, x > 0]};

AbsoluteTiming[
  csol = NDSolveValue[{advectionOp == 
      NeumannValue[0, x == 0 && ((0 < y < 0.8) || (0.9 < y < 1))], 
     bcs}, c, {x, y} \[Element] RegionShell, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {c -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-3}}]];
DensityPlot[csol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] RegionShell, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "x velocity", PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

You can see that my advection term $\boldsymbol{u}\cdot\nabla c$ is practically ignored. In it, I am trying to ensure that $\boldsymbol{u}=0$ if outside of `RegionCapillary`, but  $\boldsymbol{u}$ taken from the previous NDSolve solution otherwise. You can see that my $c=0$ `DirichletCondition` diffuses but no advection happens.

Please help me to fix this. I suspect the main problem lies in the line

```
advectionOp := 
     If[{x, y} \[Element] mr, 
       Pe {xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}.Inactive[Grad][c[x, y], {x, y}], 0] - 
      Inactive[Laplacian][c[x, y], {x, y}]
```

in which the `InterpolatingFunctions`called `xVel, yVel` are defined over the domain `RegionCapillary`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, I think that `DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, True]` is not what you want, nor what you specified in COMSOL. I think you want something like this: `DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, x > 0]` Then we get:

```
RegionCapillary = 
  RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0, 0.1}, {0.9, 0.2}], 
   Rectangle[{0, 0.8}, {0.9, 0.9}], Rectangle[{0.8, 0.2}, {0.9, 0.9}]];
RegionShell = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];

<< NDSolve`FEM`
StokesOp := {-Inactive[Laplacian][u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
    D[p[x, y], x], -Inactive[Laplacian][v[x, y], {x, y}] + 
    D[p[x, y], y],(*incompressibility div u=0*)
   Div[{u[x, y], v[x, y]}, {x, y}]};

bcs := {DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 10^3, x == 0 && y > 0.5], 
   DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && y < 0.5], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, x > 0]};

Clear[xVel, yVel, pressure];
AbsoluteTiming[{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
   NDSolveValue[{StokesOp == {0, 0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v, 
     p}, {x, y} \[Element] RegionCapillary, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-4}}, 
    "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0. &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];]
```

For making the interpolating function 0. outside the region you could set the `"ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0. &, "WarningMessage" -> False}` like documented in the [Extrapolation of Solution Domains](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) section,

```
DensityPlot[
 Sqrt[xVel[x, y]^2 + yVel[x, y]^2], {x, y} \[Element] RegionCapillary,
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "velocity magnitude", 
 PlotPoints -> 100, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
{0.306492, Null}
```

[image]

The interpolating function returns 0 outside it's original region:

```
xVel[0.5, 0.5]
0.
```

Not sure if the `Pe=10^2` is what is specified in COMSOL, if I use:

```
Pe = 100^2;
```

Thinks looks similar:

```
eqn = Pe {xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}.Grad[c[x, y], {x, y}] - 
   Laplacian[c[x, y], {x, y}];

mesh = ToElementMesh[RegionShell, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001(*,
  "MeshElementType"\[Rule]TriangleElement*)]

bcs = {DirichletCondition[c[x, y] == 0, x == 0 && 0.8 < y < 0.9], 
   DirichletCondition[c[x, y] == 1, x > 0]};

AbsoluteTiming[
 csol = NDSolveValue[{eqn == 0, bcs}, c, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];]

{0.527804, Null}

DensityPlot[csol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] RegionShell, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "x velocity", PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! This solves everything, really thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexanderErlich, glad I could help.