# Mismatch between Mathematica and COMSOL in 3D FEM problem

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation, regions, mesh, finite-element-method

I would like to solve an advection-diffusion problem on a torus domain. There are three Dirichlet conditions: One at the inlet (concentration $c=0$), one at the outlet ($c=0.5$) and one at the wall ($c=1$).

The geometry is set up in the following code. Note that `RegionCapillary` is the full solution domain, `RegionCapillary2D` is a 2D projection for convenient plotting and the list `points` goes through the centre of the tube. In the plot below `RegionCapillary` is orange and `RegionCapillary2D` is blue.

```
radiusMajor = 4;
radiusMinor = 1;
RegionCapillary = 
  ImplicitRegion[( radiusMajor - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 + z^2 <= 
     radiusMinor^2 && x >= 0, {x, y, z}];
RegionCapillary2D = 
  ImplicitRegion[( radiusMajor - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])^2 <= radiusMinor^2 &&
     x >= 0, {x, y}];
RP = RegionPlot3D[
   DiscretizeRegion /@ {RegionCapillary, RegionCapillary2D} // 
    Evaluate, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.4], Opacity[1]}];
LP = ListPointPlot3D[
   points = 
    Reverse@Table[{radiusMajor Cos[\[Phi]], radiusMajor Sin[\[Phi]] , 
       0}, {\[Phi], -Pi/2, Pi/2,  Pi/1000.0}], 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03]];
Show[RP, LP]
```

[image]

I solve the problem very similarly to user21's reply to my question ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158475/fem-ception-using-output-of-ndsolve-fem-as-input-in-another-fem-problem)). There are two parts to the problem: Stokes flow and then an advection-diffusion in which the previous (Stokes) solution provides the fluid velocity.

The Stokes problem is:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
StokesOp := {
   -Inactive[Laplacian][u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + D[p[x, y, z], x],
   -Inactive[Laplacian][v[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + D[p[x, y, z], y],
   -Inactive[Laplacian][w[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] + D[p[x, y, z], z],
   Div[{u[x, y, z], v[x, y, z], w[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}]};

inletCondition[x_, y_, z_] := x == 0 && y >= 0
outletCondition[x_, y_, z_] := x == 0 && y < 0
capillaryCondition[x_, y_, z_] := x > 0

bcs := {
   DirichletCondition[p[x, y, z] == 1, inletCondition[x, y, z]],
   DirichletCondition[p[x, y, z] == 0, outletCondition[x, y, z]],
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y, z] == 0., v[x, y, z] == 0., 
     w[x, y, z] == 0.}, capillaryCondition[x, y, z]]};

VelMMA[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[
 xVel[x, y, z]^2 + yVel[x, y, z]^2 + zVel[x, y, z]^2]

Clear[xVel, yVel, pressure];
AbsoluteTiming[{xVel, yVel, zVel, pressure} = 
   NDSolveValue[{StokesOp == {0, 0, 0, 0}, bcs}, {u, v, w, 
     p}, {x, y, z} \[Element] RegionCapillary, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, w -> 2, p -> 1}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 5 10^-3}}, 
    "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0. &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];]
```

The advection-diffusion problem is:

```
Pe = 0.7*10^4;

eqn = Pe {xVel[x, y, z], yVel[x, y, z], zVel[x, y, z]}.Grad[
      c[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] - Laplacian[c[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

bcs = {
   DirichletCondition[c[x, y, z] == 0, inletCondition[x, y, z]],
   DirichletCondition[c[x, y, z] == 0.5, outletCondition[x, y, z]],
   DirichletCondition[c[x, y, z] == 1, capillaryCondition[x, y, z]]
   };

AbsoluteTiming[
 conMMA = NDSolveValue[{eqn == 0, bcs}, 
    c, {x, y, z} \[Element] RegionCapillary, 
    Method -> {"FiniteElement", "InterpolationOrder" -> {c -> 2}, 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-3}}, 
    "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {0. &, "WarningMessage" -> False}];]
```

The velocity magnitude and concentration are plotted like this:

```
DensityPlot[
 Sqrt[xVel[x, y, 0]^2 + yVel[x, y, 0]^2 + zVel[x, y, 0]^2], {x, 
   y} \[Element] DiscretizeRegion@RegionCapillary2D, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLabel -> "velocity magnitude", PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", AspectRatio -> 2, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
DensityPlot[
 conMMA[x, y, 0], {x, y} \[Element] 
  DiscretizeRegion@RegionCapillary2D, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "concentration", PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 AspectRatio -> 2]
```

[image]

I have compared these results with an identical problem setup in COMSOL, finding that COMSOL's solution looks smoother and more plausible:
[image]

If you trace the velocity and concentration along the centreline which goes right through the tube, you can see that while both solutions satisfy $c=0.5$ at the outlet (i.e. the right hand side of the `ListPlots`), Mathematica has a very weird behaviour for the diffusion problem. The Stokes problem is largely the same between the two software packages:
[image]
I am puzzled by this discrepancy and would very much appreciate some help. My suspicion is that I am specifying the boundary conditions in Mathematica incorrectly.

**EDIT:**

With a finer mesh on both Mathematica and COMSOL, the solutions do converge somewhat, but the behaviour near the outlet of the Mathematica solution is still somewhat puzzling:
[image]

**EDIT 2: Do things get better for lower Péclet number?**

Yes. I made a comparison for `Pe=10^3`(original version is `Pe = 0.7*10^4`), finding a better convergence and less weirdness near the boundary:

[image]
[image]

The weird effects at the boundary of the `DensityPlot` are just interpolation artifacts from importing Comsol results from text file.

**EDIT 3: A more complex example**

OK, if I'm doing this, might as well go all in. Here is a more complex example of the tube, based on a looping segment with quite irregular cross-sections. Here it is plotted with centreline as well as planes which I use in inequalities to set boundary conditions in Mathematica:

[image]

A major difference to the above examples is that at the outlet there is a Neumann condition, $\boldsymbol{n}\cdot \nabla c = 0$, which in Mathematica is `NeumannValue[0, pred]`. Here is a plot of concentration and velocity accross the centreline, just as in the original examples:

[image]

You can see that once again the Stokes problem is a superb match, but the advection-diffusion problem has some serious discrepancy between solutions. Still, it is interesting that the curves are so similar and only appear to be offset. The negative concentration produced near the inlet by Mathematica is however unphysical.

Here is a pretty visualisation of with `SliceContourPlot`, which shoes how similar the cross-section profiles look:

[image]

**EDIT 4: A conclusion on 3D FEM with imported geometries**

I ended up working a lot on similarly complex imported 3D geometries as above, switching completely to Comsol was essential. The boundary conditions were getting so tricky it really helped having a visual interface. The meshing control on boundary layers was also helpful, and their constructive geometry (boolean operations on discrete regions) works ok. I ended up being very careful about ensuring flux conservation in Comsol (The best way to evaluate advective
and diffusive flux is via the `tds.ncflux_c` and `tds.ndflux_c`). My simulation results to similar problems to edit 3, made in Comsol and checked very carefully, can be seen in papers  [here](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/5/4/eaav6326)
and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08578).  In fact, in the first linked paper we even looked fluxes at cross-sections of sub-meshes ($N_j$) of quite complex vasculature, so a visual interface was enormously helpful for that:

[image]´

As for Mathematica, I gave up on trying to solve complex advection-diffusion problems on discrete 3D domains, simply because the meshing got too complicated. If you import a discrete `BoundaryMesh` in MMA, the boundary cannot easily refined: As it does not come from predefined MMA regions, options like `MaxCellMeasure` and `AccuracyGoal` cannot be used on the boundary (related question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155484/is-it-possible-to-re-mesh-downsample-upsample-a-discretizeregion-object)). Maybe the workflow with an external mesher like [gmsh](http://gmsh.info/) is the way to go here, but I haven't tried.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you use a smaller `Pe`?

Comment: Yes, see Edit 2.

Comment: I added another more complex example, perhaps it is of interest for you @user21.

Comment: You might need to consider if the PDE has a unique solution or multiple solutions. Read the following posts from the Math Stackexchange. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301914/numerically-solve-differential-equation-that-has-no-solution/2302359#comment5159707_2302359                       https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012950/why-arent-numerical-methods-sufficient-to-show-existence-and-uniqueness#comment5159646_1012950

Comment: Could you check if COMSOL uses some kind of stabilization technique (possibly automatically) in the advection diffusion module? You are looking for something called streamline-upwind/Petrov-Galerkin (SUPG). One question is if the solutions are more agreeable if you switch that off in COMSOL (just to see if that is the cause). It may be that because of the high Peclet number you need some form of what is described in  the section [Stabilization of Convection-Dominated Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html)

Comment: Another thing that's a cause for trouble is that at the boundary conditions for the concentration `c` you have jumps. 0 to 1 and 1 to 1/2. This is not physical. Just to check, try with BCs `c = 0` and `c = 1/2` and leave the `c=1` away and see if you can get the solutions to agree.

Comment: Try to use a refined mesh like so: `cf = Compile[{{coordinates, _Real,2}, {vol, _Real, 0}}, Block[{dist, x, y, z}, {x, y, z} = Mean[coordinates]; dist = (ArcTan[x, y] + \[Pi]/2)*180/\[Pi]; vol > dist*10^-4], RuntimeAttributes ->{Listable}];` and use that with `mesh = ToElementMesh[RegionCapillary, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-2, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> cf]` see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I ran some more simulations with low Peclet numbers and the agreement is generally very good. I think that the fine boundary layer structure of the high Pe case cannot be resolved by the relatively coarse mesh I chose. But the lower Pe, the less of a problem thin boundary layers become. I am hoping to write a proper answer to my question with the low Pe plots soon.

Comment: Unfortunately outlet boundary conditions for advection diffusion problem are a bit tricky. You can realize this when you write the problem in weak form. Indeed the weak contribution at the outlet section is of the kind v*J.n where J = v c + d grad c is the total flux. However, usually the outlet boundary condition is formulated by grad c.n=0. You could adjust this by using weak form to formulate the problem in comsol. I'm not sure how this can be done in mathematica

Comment: very interesting, thx for sharing these experiences with MMA and Comsol.

Comment: I have an mph file to show you how to do this. I should not post here since it's not a real solution, but maybe it can give an hint how to set this in mathematica

Comment: I am wondering if you made any progress on this and if you are still planning to write an answer?

Comment: @user21 I'm glad you continue to be interested! Yes, this has been at the back of my mind and I had some discussions with colleagues. I am definitely planning to write an answer, but please allow some time.

Comment: If you could briefly outline how you addressed the issue that would be great. It's nearly impossible to answer your question without having access to COMSOL and to see what caused the difference between the models.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I have a suggestion how to set the correct outlet boundary condition (I think this is corrupting the entire solution... at least in Comsol). The point is that the advection diffusion equation can be written as
$$
\nabla \cdot J = 0,
$$
with
$$
J=v\,c - D\nabla c
$$
where $v$ is the velocity field and $D$ is the diffusion coefficient.

The bulk lagrangian density (weak form) is
$$
\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{bulk}=-\nabla c^\dagger\cdot J
$$
where $c^\dagger$ is the test functtion, and the boundary contribution is
$$
\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{boundary}=c^\dagger J\cdot\hat{n}
$$
this is the weak form contribution to use in place of the outlet boundary condition. This avoid the ripples for the concentration field at the outlet. Here is the solution with a computed velocity field for $Pe=100$ (almost advection dominated problem)

Comment: In Comsol I am using the transport of dilute species package, which has a predefined type "outlet" which is $n\cdot\nabla c=0$. I think in Mathematica this should simply be taken care of by `NeumannValue[0, pred]`.

Comment: You can add a "weak contribution" in comsol and obtain the results I posted... isn't this becoming a comsol-related discussion?! :)

Comment: I'd be quite interested to have a look at your Comsol file, feel free to email me at alexander.erlich@gmail.com if you like.