# Automatic solution to label boundary elements with BoundaryMarkerFunction

Tags: differential-equations, regions, computational-geometry, finite-element-method, mesh

## Preparations

Mathematica 11.3, Windows.

Let us say I have a rectangular region with 10 little holes inside. Their coordinates are given by `positionList`. The resulting region `mr` is made through `RegionDifference` and `RegionUnion` of disks and rectangles:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

radius = 0.1;
Louter = 2;
OuterRegion = Rectangle[{-L/2, -L/2}, {L/2, L/2}] /. L -> Louter;

positionList = {{0.706`, -0.14`}, {0.389`, 0.593`}, {-0.278`, 
    0.429`}, {0.254`, 
    0.844`}, {-0.46`, -0.367`}, {0.737`, -0.759`}, {-0.07`, -0.664`}, \
{-0.469`, 0.626`}, {-0.755`, -0.509`}, {-0.455`, -0.015`}};
diskRegions = Disk[#, radius] & /@ positionList;
mr = RegionDifference[OuterRegion, RegionUnion@diskRegions];

LP = ListPlot[positionList -> Table[k, {k, 1, Length@positionList}]];
RP = Show[mr // RegionPlot, LP, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

The labels of the disks show the order in which they appear in `positionList`. Ultimately I want a FEM mesh where I can apply specific boundary conditions on disk 1, disk 2, disk 3 etc. First, I make a boundary mesh:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionBoundary@mr, 
   "RegionHoles" -> positionList, "BoundaryGroupingThreshold" -> 0, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 1];
Show[bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]], 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

## Problem

As you can see, the **Region Markers are scrambled**! In the boundary mesh, the hole corresponding to disk 2 (in the blue plot above) actually has marker 14. Hole 3 has marker 13, and so on.

**I want the markers of the boundary mesh to be consistent with the disk numbers, here going from 1 to 10. The markers on the walls should have numbers 11-14.**

## A manual solution

I have solved this problem with a `BoundaryMarkerFunction`, writing a condition manually for each disk and each of the walls:

```
boundaryMarkerFunction = 
  Compile[{{boundaryElementCoords, _Real, 
     3}, {pointMarkres, _Integer, 2}},
   Module[{pt1 = #[[1]], pt2 = #[[2]]},
      Which[

       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[1]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[1]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[1]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[1]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 1,
       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[2]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[2]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[2]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[2]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 2,
       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[3]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[3]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[3]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[3]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 3,
       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[4]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[4]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[4]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[4]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 4,
       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[5]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[5]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[5]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[5]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 5,
       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[6]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[6]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[6]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[6]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 6,
       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[7]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[7]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[7]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[7]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 7,
       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[8]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[8]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[8]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[8]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 8,
       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[9]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[9]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[9]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[9]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 9,
       (pt1[[1]] - positionList[[10]][[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - 
            positionList[[10]][[2]])^2 < 
         1.1 radius^2 && (pt2[[1]] - 
            positionList[[10]][[1]])^2 + (pt2[[2]] - 
            positionList[[10]][[2]])^2 < 1.1 radius^2 , 10,
       pt1[[1]] < -0.99 && pt2[[1]] < -0.99, 11, (* left wall *)
       pt1[[2]] < -0.99 && pt2[[2]] < -0.99, 12, (* bottom wall *)
       pt1[[1]] > 0.99 && pt2[[1]] > 0.99, 13, (* right wall *)
       pt1[[2]] > 0.99 && pt2[[2]] > 0.99, 14, (* top wall *)

       True, 4 ]] & /@ boundaryElementCoords];

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionBoundary@mr, 
   "RegionHoles" -> positionList, "BoundaryGroupingThreshold" -> 0, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 2, 
   "BoundaryMarkerFunction" -> boundaryMarkerFunction];
{Show[bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]], 
  ImageSize -> 400], RP}
```

[image]
[image]

## An automatic solution?

Could this be automated, so I can vary the number of disks? I would have happily replaced the `Which` construct by some `Table`, but I am not sure what kind of arguments this mysterious `boundaryMarkerFunction` takes. For instance, I tried

```
boundaryMarkerFunction[bmesh["BoundaryElements"], 
 bmesh["Coordinates"]]
```

which fails because `boundaryElementCoords` is supposed to be 3D.

**Please help me find an automatic solution to label the boundary elements in my desired order.**

## Just for fun

This allows us to use `ElementMarker` with `NDSolve`, specifying precise individual boundary conditions on the disks. For instance, here is the heat equation with a different `DirichletCondition` on each disk:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionBoundary@mr, 
   "RegionHoles" -> positionList, "BoundaryGroupingThreshold" -> 0, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 4, 
   "BoundaryMarkerFunction" -> boundaryMarkerFunction];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];

boundaryMarkerList = Table[k, {k, 1, Length@positionList}];

op = - Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 0.1 u[x, y];
BCedges = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, ElementMarker == 11], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, ElementMarker == 13]};
BCcircles = 
  Table[DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
    ElementMarker == k], {k, 1, Length@positionList}];
BC = Join[BCedges, BCcircles];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, BC}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]

{
 DensityPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Temperature", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400],
 Show[mesh["Wireframe"], ImageSize -> 400]
 }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you share the answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159506/18437) question I will help you here.

Comment: @user21 That question has torus geometry part, where reducing Pe number and increasing mesh precision clearly helped (see edits 1 & 2 in my question). The discrepancy on imported 3D geometry (edit 3) is a more difficult problem. I ended up spending a lot of time simulating this in Comsol, carefully checking flux conservation, resulting in two papers, [here](https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/5/4/eaav6326)
and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.08578). I describe my thoughts in more detail in a new EDIT 4 in that question. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `ElementMarker` are attributed automatically there is no way that they would fit all possible orderings one could think of. The work flow is that one would generate the boundary mesh and the use, for example, a `Manipulate` to scroll through the boundaries. Something like this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

radius = 0.1;
Louter = 2;
OuterRegion = Rectangle[{-L/2, -L/2}, {L/2, L/2}] /. L -> Louter;

positionList = {{0.706`, -0.14`}, {0.389`, 0.593`}, {-0.278`, 
    0.429`}, {0.254`, 
    0.844`}, {-0.46`, -0.367`}, {0.737`, -0.759`}, {-0.07`, -0.664`}, \
{-0.469`, 0.626`}, {-0.755`, -0.509`}, {-0.455`, -0.015`}};
diskRegions = Disk[#, radius] & /@ positionList;
r = RegionDifference[OuterRegion, RegionUnion@diskRegions];

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[r, "BoundaryGroupingThreshold" -> 0];
bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}

Manipulate[
 Show[
  Graphics[Text["ElementMarker = " <> ToString[marker], {0, 1.1}]],
  bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> Gray]],
  bmesh["Wireframe"[(ElementMarker == marker), 
    "MeshElementStyle" -> Red]],
  PlotRange -> 1.2*bmesh["Bounds"]
  ], {marker, bmesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]}, 
 ControlType -> Slider]
```

[image]

If you want to set specific markers you have two options. Either use the the `BoundaryMarkerFunction` and `PointMarkerFunction` documented in `ToElementMesh` or construct the components separately and merge them in the order your would like to have. I am going to show the second method.

We start by generating boundary meshes for each of the components.

```
bmOuter = ToBoundaryMesh[OuterRegion];
bmDisks = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[#, AccuracyGoal -> 1, 
     "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.05, 
     "BoundaryGroupingThreshold" -> 0] & /@ diskRegions;
```

An advantage of this approach is that you have exact control over each component. Next, we are going to merge them.

**Update**

The helper function below can be installed from the [FEMAddOns paclet](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) with the use of the [FEMAddOnsInstall](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FEMAddOnsInstall) resource function.

This will install the [FEMAddOns paclet](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns)

```
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
```

And you can then use `BoundaryElementMeshJoin` (and other Boolean operations) as in the code below.

**End Update**

For this we write a helper function:

```
BoundaryElementMeshJoin[bm1_, bm2_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[ToBoundaryMesh]] := 
 Module[{c1, c2, nc1, newBCEle, newPEle, eleTypes, markers},
  c1 = bm1["Coordinates"];
  c2 = bm2["Coordinates"];
  nc1 = Length[c1];

  newBCEle = bm2["BoundaryElements"];
  eleTypes = Head /@ newBCEle;
  If[ElementMarkersQ[newBCEle],
   markers = ElementMarkers[newBCEle];
   If[ElementMarkersQ[bm1["BoundaryElements"]],
    markers += Max[ElementMarkers[bm1["BoundaryElements"]]]
    ];
   ,
   markers = Sequence[]
   ];
  newBCEle = 
   MapThread[#1[##2] &, {eleTypes, ElementIncidents[newBCEle] + nc1, 
     markers}];

  newPEle = bm2["PointElements"];
  eleTypes = Head /@ newPEle;
  If[ElementMarkersQ[newPEle],
   markers = ElementMarkers[newPEle];
   If[ElementMarkersQ[bm1["PointElements"]],
    markers += Max[ElementMarkers[bm1["PointElements"]]]
    ];
   ,
   markers = Sequence[]
   ];
  newPEle = 
   MapThread[#1[##2] &, {eleTypes, ElementIncidents[newPEle] + nc1, 
     markers}];

  ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> Join[c1, c2], 
   "BoundaryElements" -> Flatten[{bm1["BoundaryElements"], newBCEle}],
    "PointElements" -> Flatten[{bm1["PointElements"], newPEle}], opts
   ]
  ]

BoundaryElementMeshJoin[r1_, r2_, r3__] := 
  BoundaryElementMeshJoin[BoundaryElementMeshJoin[r1, r2], r3];
```

`BoundaryElementMeshJoin` works by appending the mesh elements from a second boundary mesh to the first. It tests if markers are present and in case they are the marker indices are shifted by the maximum marker index present in the first mesh. It does the same for point element markers.

We can now merge the boundary meshes in any way we like and thus affect the numbering of the markers.

```
bmesh = BoundaryElementMeshJoin @@ Flatten[{bmDisks, bmOuter}]
```

Now, we want a high quality mesh. In stead of calling `ToElementMesh` on the boundary mesh, we note that have the symbolic region available. To make use of that we use `ToNumericalRegion`

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[r];
```

We now assign the boundary mesh just generated to that numerical region

```
SetNumericalRegionElementMesh[nr, bmesh]
```

When we now call `ToElementMesh` the mesh can be second order accurate with curved boundaries; because curved nodes can be derived from the symbolic region `r`.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[nr]

mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"]
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}

mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
  "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]]
```

[image]

One thing to think about is that `DirichletCondition` uses the `PointElement` marker and not the `BoundaryElement` marker. So you need to make sure that this:

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
      "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Red, 
      PlotRange -> #]] & /@ {{{-1.2, -0.8}, {0.8, 1.2}}, {{0.8, 
      1.2}, {0.8, 1.2}}, {{-1.2, -0.8}, {-1.2, -0.8}}, {{0.8, 
      1.2}, {-1.2, -0.8}}}, 2]]
```

[image]

Is what you want. If not, you have the option to use something like `x==1` and so forth in the respective `DirichletCondition` or generate a boundary mesh with the markers you want. Something like this:

```
bmOuter = 
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        1}}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]}, 
   "PointElements" -> {PointElement[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {11, 11, 13,
        13}]}];
bmesh = BoundaryElementMeshJoin @@ Flatten[{bmDisks, bmOuter}];
nr = ToNumericalRegion[r];
SetNumericalRegionElementMesh[nr, bmesh];
mesh = ToElementMesh[nr];
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
      "MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Red, 
      PlotRange -> #]] & /@ {{{-1.2, -0.8}, {0.8, 1.2}}, {{0.8, 
      1.2}, {0.8, 1.2}}, {{-1.2, -0.8}, {-1.2, -0.8}}, {{0.8, 
      1.2}, {-1.2, -0.8}}}, 2]]
```

[image]

This would lead you to:

```
op = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 0.1 u[x, y];
BCedges = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, ElementMarker == 11], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, ElementMarker == 13]};
BCcircles = 
  Table[DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == RandomReal[{0, 1}], 
    ElementMarker == k], {k, 1, Length@positionList}];
BC = Join[BCedges, BCcircles];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, BC}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]

{DensityPlot[ufun[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
  ColorFunction -> "Temperature", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400], 
 Show[mesh["Wireframe"], ImageSize -> 400]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There probably is a better way to do this, but I extracted the LineElements from bmesh and replaced the markers if they were in a particular disk region else a rectangular region.

## Original OP Code

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
radius = 0.1;
Louter = 2;
OuterRegion = Rectangle[{-L/2, -L/2}, {L/2, L/2}] /. L -> Louter;
positionList = {{0.706`, -0.14`}, {0.389`, 0.593`}, {-0.278`, 
    0.429`}, {0.254`, 
    0.844`}, {-0.46`, -0.367`}, {0.737`, -0.759`}, {-0.07`, -0.664`}, \
{-0.469`, 0.626`}, {-0.755`, -0.509`}, {-0.455`, -0.015`}};
diskRegions = Disk[#, radius] & /@ positionList;
mr = RegionDifference[OuterRegion, RegionUnion@diskRegions];
LP = ListPlot[positionList -> Table[k, {k, 1, Length@positionList}]];
RP = Show[mr // RegionPlot, LP, ImageSize -> 400]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[RegionBoundary@mr, 
   "RegionHoles" -> positionList, "BoundaryGroupingThreshold" -> 0, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 1];
Show[bmesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]], 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

## Helper Functions

I created a list of region functions for the disks and a function `diskIDfn` to return the particular disk a point was in.  Then I created a function to replace the markers depending the diskID or if it were on the rectangular boundary.

```
(* Determine if Point Lies in Dilated Disk Region *)
rmDiskFns = RegionMember[Disk[#, 1.05 radius]] & /@ positionList;
diskIDfn = (First@FirstPosition[Through[rmDiskFns[#]], True]) &;
(* Replace Marker From to be defined list *)
replaceMarker[l_] := 
 With[{rpl = ReplaceAll[{3 -> 11, 4 -> 12, 5 -> 13, 2 -> 14}]},
  If[NumericQ[First@l],
   LineElement[l[[2]], l[[3]] /. {First@l[[3]] -> First@l}],
   LineElement[l[[2]], rpl@l[[3]]]
   ]
  ]
```

## Renumbering the Mesh

I extracted the coordinates and the list of LineElements from `bmesh` and created a substitution list to replace the markers.

```
(* Extract Coordinates and Boundary Elements *)
crd = bmesh["Coordinates"];
bes = bmesh["BoundaryElements"];
(* Create Substitution List *)
(* {newMarkerID,line element list, old marker list} *)
lelmMat = {diskIDfn@crd[[First@Flatten@#1]], #1, #2} & @@@ bes;
(* Replace Markers *)
bcEle = replaceMarker /@ lelmMat;
(* Re-boundary mesh and show new labels *)
bmeshnew = 
  ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, "BoundaryElements" -> bcEle, 
   "RegionHoles" -> positionList];
Show[bmeshnew["Wireframe"["MeshElementMarkerStyle" -> Blue]], 
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image: Renumbered Boundary Mesh]

Note well that you will need to change the accuracy goal in the original `bmesh` definition to get a refined mesh.  I changed the accuracy goal to 4 and repeated the process to generate the following element mesh.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmeshnew];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Full Mesh]